# Manga about possessed child who develops a taste for people

Tags: kurozakuro

- The main character was a young (probably 10–15 years old) boy who was possessed by some sort of demon (so, fantasy); a tree might have been related here
- This might have caused him to (want to?) eat people
- Said possession happens during the course of the book, and the character is still himself, only more… evil
- The cover was this character with a sharp-toothed grin
- The title was one word starting with K
- It was a series
- I found the first in the series in [a book store](http://www.bolen.bc.ca/) somewhere between 2007 and 2011; it was the only one there at the time

This is a bit of a stretch and it’s been so long that I’m not completely sure of any of the details. Still, if anything can be found from it…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We confirmed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21545988#21545988) that this is [Kurozakuro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurozakuro). Here's the plot synopsis from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/manga/1063/Kurozakuro):

> This is the story of a wuss named Sakurai Mikito who one day swallows the creation of a creature called Zakuro and becomes an "oni", a superhuman creature with a taste for human flesh. As Mikito is horrified by this change in his once-gentle nature, he decides to leave on a journey with an oni-hunter in order to discover a way to turn back to normal.

Essentially everything matches the description in the OP. The first volume of the manga was released in English in November 2010 by Viz media. The series was finished in English at 7 volumes a year later in November 2011.

Here's the (Japanese) volume 1 cover:

[image: Kurozakuro volume 1 cover]